# A question on alternating product and $SL_n(R)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, exterior-algebra, tangent-spaces

I am reading Fulton and Harris representation theory.

In the section 8.2 - Examples of Lie Algebras, while calculating the Lie algebra of $SL_n(\mathbb R),$ the author tell that by definition $$ A_t(e_1) \wedge\cdots \wedge A_t(e_n) \equiv e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_n$$ for any basis $\{e_i\} $ of $\mathbb R ^n$ where $\{ A_t\}$ is an arc in $SL_n(\mathbb R)$ with $A_0 = I$ and $A_0' = X$

Can someone tell me exactly what defintion to the author is referring, I have looked appendix where exterior product is defined and earlier chapters, I am not able to find out in the book.

Comment: For the top exterior power of $V$ (i.e. the wedge product of $n$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional space), and a linear map $A: V \to V$, we have $(A e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge A e_n) = (\det A) e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_n$. Some take this as the *definition* of the determinant of a linear map. Since your $A$ is in $SL_n$ it has determinant 1.

Comment: I think that answers the question.